# Can PriorValue or any other code/formula be used to show the prior and new value of the field(s) to be approved in the approval email?

Tags: visualforce

Can PriorValue or any other code/formula be used to show the prior and new value of the field(s) to be approved in the approval email?

Please give me answer to all people because i need many idea and way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the priorvalue function in a field update to write the value to a custom field.  Then use the custom field in your email template.  Field updates fire before email alerts so the data will reflect properly.